# Update state using function .map() is mutated state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still new to react and I still don't really understand about mutated the state.

I have seen many posts about this but I do not understand how the mutation process happened so I think it is necessary to ask this.

**First i need to know is this called mutated state?**

```
this.setState(prevState=>({
        colors:this.state.colors.map((c,i)=>{
            return{
                original_color:c.original_color,
                hex_color:c.hex_color,
                isActive:false
            }
        })
    }))
```

**OR**

```
let newData = this.state.colors.map((c,i)=>{
            return{
                original_color:c.original_color,
                hex_color:c.hex_color,
                isActive:false
            }
        })

        this.setState({
            colors: newData
        })
```

in this case i just want to set all of this value `isActive` to `false`

**Last**

i want to set this value to empty

```
  this.setState({
            colors:[]
        })
```

Comment: map and returning like the way you do, doesn't mutate the state in any of the above manner. However in first pattern you need to use it like `this.setState(prevState=>({
        colors:prevState.colors.map((c,i)=>{
            return{
                original_color:c.original_color,
                hex_color:c.hex_color,
                isActive:false
            }
        })
    }))`. Also mutation means to update the value at the same reference

Comment: how about the last case? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: setState doesn't mutate the original array. it creates a new copy of it.

Comment: Mutated state : `this.state.colors = YourObject`, In both case you are not doing this, both seems fine

Answer (score 1):

Since `.map()` returns a new array as a result, using it is safe and is not considered a mutation.

Basically, anything that doesn't change the original state or any direct references to it, is not considered a mutation.

Answer (score 0):

Your state is not mutated in any case. `.map()` returns a new array. Your state is only mutated when you directly assign it to another value without calling `.setState()` like so:

```
this.state.value = anotherValue;
```

Or:

```
this.state.value.push(anotherValue)
```